# how to call async inside another async

Tags: node.js, node-postgres

I am trying to get some data using an API with an accessToken which is encrypted in the database, I am fetching it then decrypting so I can use it to make the API call as follows:

```
async function getUserGuilds(discord_id) {

//Get Token
const tokenQuery = 'SELECT e_accesstoken FROM users WHERE discord_id = $1';
const discordID = [discord_id];
db.query(tokenQuery, discordID, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else if (!err) {
        const encryptedAccessToken = res.rows[0].e_accesstoken
        const decrypted = decrypt(encryptedAccessToken);
        const accessToken = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    }
})

//Call the API after getting the token
const response = await fetch(`${DISCORD_API}/users/@me/guilds`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
    }
});
  return response.json();
}
```

as you can see the accessToken is outside the scope, how can I access it and use it for the API call? What is the best practice?

Comment: You say in a comment _"Call the API after getting the token"_. **After** the token is retrieved from the database, the callback passed as the third argument to `db.query()` is executed. The commented code runs when `db.query()` returns and this happens before the response from the database arrives (that's the point of passing it a callback function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Since you are using async keywork, this function automatically returns
// a Promise, therefore you will need to handle it with a .then() or await
// in order to get the result.
async function getUserGuilds(discord_id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //Get Token
    const tokenQuery = 'SELECT e_accesstoken FROM users WHERE discord_id = $1';
    const discordID = [discord_id];

    db.query(tokenQuery, discordID, async (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        // Rejecting the promise error here will stop the execution, therefore you will not need to
        // add an else statement
        return reject(error);
      }


      const encryptedAccessToken = res.rows[0].e_accesstoken
      const decrypted = decrypt(encryptedAccessToken);
      const accessToken = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

      // Always wrap async operations with try/catch because they will fail
      // at some point, therefore your code must be prepared to handle it
      try {
        //Call the API after getting the token
        const response = await fetch(`${DISCORD_API}/users/@me/guilds`, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` }
        });

        resolve(response.json());
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }  
    });
  });
}
```

The tip is, as soon you start to dealing with asynchronous code, try to write you own functions in an asynchronous manner.

Comment: If it helps you, don't forget to mark it as an answer. :)

Comment: I see, I got your point :) it's my first time using Async. The code you write is giving an error here: const response = await fetch(`${DISCORD_API}/users/@me/guilds`. SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: Fixed it. Basically it was the `async` keyword missing here: `db.query(tokenQuery, discordID, async (err, res) => {...`

Comment: That fixed the issue. But, does it return the data from the API because I am getting undefined as a result. I am guessing because there are two async, one at the start of the function and one inside db.query()

Comment: How are you calling `getUserGuilds()` this function?

Comment: Like this :
router.get('/guilds',isAuthorized , async (req, res) => {
    const userID = req.user.discord_id;
    const userGuilds = await getUserGuilds(userID);
    console.log(userGuilds);
    if (userID) {
        res.send(userGuilds);
    } else {
        res.send('No User')
    }
})

Comment: If you console.log() inside the function `getUserGuils()`, do you see the results?

Comment: I made a change on the previous answer by returning a Promise object in the root of the function and then called resolve() and reject() where they are needed.

Comment: The last change you made brought back data!. I will have to read more into it and try to understand how all that works, so much new information :)

Comment: Take a look at this article for further reading: https://scotch.io/courses/10-need-to-know-javascript-concepts/callbacks-promises-and-async